# Cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python

I have a problem..

In my `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/re.py` is this function:

```
def search(pattern, string, flags=0):
    """Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
```

I call this function with this line:

```
total = int(re.sub("[',\. ]", "", re.search("(([0-9]+[',\. ])*[0-9]+)", totalText).group(1)))
```

But I get this error:

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `totalText` is not a string, decode it to string. Something like `totalText.decode()` should get the job done

Comment: totalText seems to be bytes-like so prepend your strings with b to make them also bytes-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `totalText` is not what you expect. Try substituting it with `totalText.decode()`.